# Android Studio.Obtener resultado Uri de una grabacion.Se puede con Media Recorder?Con Intent no pude.O los tel ya no traen metodo nativo?

Tags: android-studio, activity, android-intent, audio, uri

//No hay mucha info sobre este tema y ya lo elegimos para desarrollar y bueno queremos hacerlo bien. En developers hablan de Uri de fotos y Video pero nada de archivos de sonido.

```
private Button mRecordBtn;
private TextView mRecordLabel;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private String archivoSalida;

mRecordLabel = findViewById( R.id.recordLabel );
mRecordBtn = findViewById( R.id.recordBtn );

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PostActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1000);
    }

mRecordBtn.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                startRecording();

                mRecordBtn.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.rec );
                mRecordLabel.setText( "Grabando..." );

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                stopRecording();
                mRecordLabel.setText( "El Audio a Sido Grabado" );
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

//Lo estoy haciendo así pero no se como crear un metodo para crear un archivo Uri.
La grabadora funciona perfecto pero quiero un Uri para hacer otra actividad luego.
Y es mejor obtener un archivo .MP3 o un archivo .3GP?

```
 private void startRecording () {
    archivoSalida = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Grabacion.3gp" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC );
    recorder.setOutputFormat( MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP );
    recorder.setAudioEncoder( MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB );
    recorder.setOutputFile( archivoSalida );

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
}

private void stopRecording () {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
}

public void reproducir (View view){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource( archivoSalida );
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {

    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

//Es un proyecto para un curso que estamos haciendo y el profesor no nos puede ayudar.espero alguien nos entienda somos un poco nuevo en esto. Gracias amigos!

Comment: Cual es el error desplegado en el LogCat?, agrega detalles a tu pregunta, revisa [ask],saludos.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes si perdon. Queremos conocer el metodo para poder obtener un Uri. Haci la grabadora no da ningun error pero no esta terminado nuestro proyecto y no sabemos como continuar. discupe no hay este tipo de informacion en la red.probamos muchas opciones pero nada funciona no hicimos nada concreto la verdad.gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente me parece que el nombre de archivo lo estas guardando incorrectamente, usa como sufijo la fecha en milisegundos y despuès define la extensiòn del archivo que en este caso es .3gp:

```
 //archivoSalida = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Grabacion.3gp" + System.currentTimeMillis();
archivoSalida = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Grabacion"+ System.currentTimeMillis() +".3gp";
```

**Como obtener uri a partir de una ruta de archivo.**

En este caso tienes la ruta del archivo donde guardaràs la grabaciòn, es importante asegurar que se haya creado el archivo en la ruta especificada:

```
archivoSalida = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Grabacion"+ System.currentTimeMillis() +".3gp";
```

A partir de esa ruta, puedes obtener la `Uri` de esta forma:

```
File file = new File(archivoSalida);

Uri uriArchivo = Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.Ahora provaremos si funciona nuestro codigo.Habia echo una pregunta pero lo pregunto aca.Se puede hacer todo esto que estamos haciendo pero con el metodo Intent?Seria crear el intent para grabar y terminar con onActivityResult y ahi obtener el archivo Uri.Gracias de antemano al que nos saque esta duda.

Comment: Claro, de hecho puedes enviar en el Intent el path del archivo y al recibirlo en onActivityResult() obtener el Uri

Comment: Muy buenas tardes. La solucion brindada anteriormente funciono muy bien mil gracias. Queriamos saber si podria brindarnos ese metodo que comenta usted en el comentario anterior.seria de mucha ayuda para saber otra alternativa para hacerlo.muchas gracias por su tiempo aprendimos mucho en su respuesta!